# Selection of CAPL Test Module programmatically

Tags: capl, canoe

I want to know if we can control the selection/deselection of checkboxes of the CAPL Test Modules via CAPL Scripts, either by setting some system variable or by calling certain events. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is actually possible:

> Use Start to define when the test module is to be started:
>
> - Immediately after start of measurement.
> - When the defined environment variable switches to a value unequal to 0 during measurement.   -When the defined system variable switches to
>     a value unequal to 0 during measurement.
> - When a defined key is pressed during measurement.
>
> You can start the test modules manually in the execution dialog, in
>   the test module's context menu or by using the arrow button on the
>   test module block in the Simulation Setup. Test modules can be started
>   several times during a measurement. You can therefore define (and use)
>   several start conditions. During the runtime of a test module it is
>   not possible to start it again.

CANoe help Test module : Configuration dialog

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the test module and select configuration
Use Start to define when the test module is to be started:

- define system variable: starts the test module if value unequal to 0 during measurement.

use the system variable wherever you want for e.g. create a panel and assign it to a button or a switch (don't forget to configure the 'on' & 'off' value)
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think it is entirely impossible to change the selected tests **during** test execution. I suppose you could activate/deactivate test modules with the COM interface but certainly not during test execution.